# unmarked number in a circle

Tags: combinatorics

The integers from  $1$ to $1000$ are written in order around a circle. Starting from $1$ every $15$ th number is marked $\left\{1,15,31,\right\}.$ The process is continued until a number is reached which has already been marked. Then unmarked unmbers are

what i try

first i calculate marked numbers

$\left\{1,15,31,\cdots,991\right\}$

$\left\{2,16,32,\cdots ,992\right\}$

$\left\{3,17,33,\cdots,993\right\}$

$\left\{4,18,34,\cdots ,994\right\}$

$\left\{5,19,35,\cdots,995\right\}$

$\left\{6,20,36,\cdots ,996\right\}$

$\left\{7,21,37,\cdots,997\right\}$

$\left\{8,22,38,\cdots ,998\right\}$

$\left\{9,23,39,\cdots,999\right\}$

$\left\{10,24,40,\cdots ,1000\right\}$

help me to solve it pleaee

Comment: $15-1=14$, $31-15=16$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to have a mistake you say "every 15th number" but then you increment by 14 and then by 16. Then you get to 991 which is correct but then you incorrectly got 2 on your next line when 991+15=1006=6 (mod 1000) Thus the next line should have started at 6 and continued {21,36,51,...981,996}, and the next line should have gone {11,26,41,...971,986} After 986, you would repeat 1 so we stop here.

Another approach:
lcm(15,1000)=3000
(i.e. it will take 3 cycles around the circle to end back at the starting point).
Thus the number of marked numbers is (1000/15)*3=200.

Therefore (since you chose to start at 1 instead of 0 and end at 1000 instead of 999) the list of marked numbers will include all the numbers which are 1 greater than a multiple of 5: {1,6,11,16,21,26,...,981,986,991,996}

The unmarked numbers are just the other numbers: {2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,12,...994,995,997,998,999,1000}

Answer (score 2):

A number $n\in I_{1000}=\{1, 2, \dotsc, 1000\}$ is marked if and only if there exist $i, j\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$
15i+1=n+1000j\Leftrightarrow n-1=5(3i-200j)
$$
observe that
$$
3\cdot 67 -200 = 201-200 = 1\Rightarrow n-1 =5(3\cdot 67k-200k)=5k
$$
then $n$ is markable if and only if $n-1$ is a $5$ multiple or
$$
n=\{1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, \dotsc, 996\}
$$

Comment: I believe that there is something wrong in your iff on the first line. Should it not be $n= 5(3i - 200j) +1$?

Comment: Oh right, now I edit it